# Javascript returning a value from a function

Tags: javascript

Here is a simplified version of my function and calling it.

When i console log the gameOver it should be "Treasure" or Huntress or false

```
// calling the function

var gameOver = this._checkGameOver;

_checkGameOver(){

            var round = 1;
            var gold = this._deck.filter(x => x =='Treasure').length;
            var trap = this._deck.filter(x => x =='Trap').length; 

            if(gold == 0){
            return('Adventurer');
            }
            else if(trap == 0 || round == 5){
            return('Huntress');
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: seems like you're not calling the function/method

Comment: `console.log(gameOver())`

Comment: Use `()` to call a function: `var gameOver = this._checkGameOver();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the actual method to `gameOver`, not its return value. Make your function call as follows:

```
let gameOver = this._checkGameOver();
```

Comment: This is such a common occurrence, do you think that perhaps there might be a duplicate for it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't call the function.

Try gameOver() instead of gameOver